# Flex application memory usage

Tags: apache-flex

`System.totalMemory` gives the total memory used by the flash player and not one particular application.  Is there any way I can get the flex application's memory usage in code/actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

The [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) gives you an object by object readout of memory usage, but it makes you call out to it as a separate air application, which you may not want to do in production code. It's open source though, so it might be worth a look at how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great open source actionscript only resource meter https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats